# Elasticsearch - text type regexp

Tags: elasticsearch

Does elasticsearch support regex search on text type string?

I created a document like below.

```
{
  "T": "a$b$c$d"
}
```

and I tried to search this document with below query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "T:/a.*/"
    }
  }
}
```

It seems work for me, BUT when I tried to query with '$' symbol. It's unable to find the document.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "T:/a$.*/"
    }
  }
}
```

How should I do to find the document? This key data should be text type(not keyword) since it can be longer than keyword max length.

Comment: The issue here is that `a$b$c$d` gets analyzed by the default standard analyzer and the indexed tokens are `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. However, your query would work on `T.keyword` in this specific case, but maybe not others.

Comment: You should set custom analyzer

Comment: I need to find string that 'c' char is shown after 'a' char. is it able to find it with custom analyzer?

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of some things, here:

- If your field is analyzed (and tokenized in the process) you will only find matches in fields containing a token (not the whole "text") that matches your RegExp. If you want the whole content of the field to match, you must use a keyword field or at least a [Keyword Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) that doesn't tokenize your text.
- The `$` symbol has a special meaning in Regular Expressions (it marks the end of a string), so you'll have to escape it: `a\$.*`
- Your RegExp must match a whole token to get a hit. That's why there's no point to use `$` as a (non-escaped) RegExp symbol: Your RegExp **must** match a whole token from beginning to end, anyway. So (to stick to your example) to match fields where `a` is followed by `c`, you'd need `.*?a[^c]*c.*`, or if you *need* the `$`s in there, escape them: `.*?a\$[^c]*c\$.*`

Comment: thank you for this explanation. could you link to the ES documentation where it mentions that text fields with analysers are unsupported for regex. I was stuck for quite a while trying to run regex queries on text. After some googling, I came to know only keyword fields can be used. But I don't find this info in the official docs

Comment: [This page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html) gives a list of full text query types to search analyzed fields (as this is what they are for) and also explains how queries on such fields work: *"The full text queries enable you to search analyzed text fields such as the body of an email. The query string is processed using the same analyzer that was applied to the field during indexing."*.